# Podspec Error: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file

Tags: cocoapods, podspec, cocoapods-1.2

I am creating cocoa pod test library. I added podspec file to it as

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "TestFrame"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A short description of TestFrame."
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/{user}/{project}"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  s.author                = { "Shubham" => "{email}" }
  s.ios.deployment_target = "10.0"
  s.swift_version         = "4.2"
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/{User}/{project}.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
  s.source_files = "TestFrame.h", "Test.swift"
end
```

When I do `pod lib lint --allow-warnings` validation gets success but when I do `pod trunk push --allow-warnings` I get validation error

```
- ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.
```

I tried many combinations randomly for `s.source_files` but many a times I get above error.

My project structure

```
--TestFrame
  --TestFrame
    --TestFrame.h
    --Test.swift
    --Info.plist
```

My problem is I don't know what to write in as `source_files`.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72014042/1293445

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have a `0.0.1` tag on the `https://github.com/{User}/{project}.git` repo.

If you need to do additional diagnosis, run `pod spec lint --verbose --no-clean ...`