# iOS file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to create a `CocoaPod` and when I try `pod lib lint` there's an error about `ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The`source_files`pattern did not match any file.`

I am trying to follow `BlinkingLabel` pod as an example and using `Gitlab` for storage of my `.git` . I tagged it successfully `1.0.0` and it worked for it.

[image]

I used my `CocoaPod` in `Example for Pod` and its working but I got the error:

```
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.5

 -> BlinkingLabel (1.0.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')

[!] BlinkingLabel did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
You can use the `--no-clean` option to inspect any issue.
```

My `source_file` prop is:

```
s.source_files = 'BlinkingLabel/Classes/**/*'
```

But I've tried it with:

```
s.source_files  = "BlinkingLabel/**/*"



s.source_files = 'BlinkingLabel/BlinkingLabel.swift'



s.source_files = 'BlinkingLabel/Classes/**/*.{h,m,c}'
```

No one has worked for me in lint.

And there's a strange thing.

In the article and examples it recommended to use with `BlinkingLabel/Classes/**/*` but there's nothing any directory as named `Classes` in `BlinkingLabel`, I guess because of new update of `CocoaPod` or maybe something is different in new `CocoaPod`. Can you explain this?

And how to solve this problem for `pod lib lint` at all?

Edit: I've searched over `stackoverflow` but nothing work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone who stuck at `- ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The`source_files`pattern did not match any file.`, do not use `source_files` like below.

```
s.source_files = 'BlinkingLabel/Classes/**/*'
```

Use it with your inner directory name and exact file type.

For example if you have a `Handler.swift` file it must be.

```
s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*.swift'
```

If you have any `.c` file in your pod project that used

```
s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*.c'
```

or you can `mix` it with `different file types`.

Further I realized that the you must not trust to `Classes` directory.

You can create a `Sources` directory and can add all your source files into it and then you can try it with

```
s.source_files     =   'Sources/**/*.swift'
```

This is the exact solution for me.

I hope it helps for anyone who stuck at.

Comment: WOW .... Its worked created new Sources directory.. and same found nothing on stack for like one hr than i found you :D

Comment: It worked for me as well, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I regret to ask the question.

It worked now.

```
s.source_files = 'BlinkingLabel/Classes/**/*'
```

I've not changed anything but it worked. That's strange.

Comment: if you haven't changed anything and then it has worked then I'd just delete the question. If you did something to fix it then its fine to keep the question and include its answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have your files and source_files is appointed to that folder, and then check lint locally

```
pod lib lint YPlayer.podspec
```

if all ok, then you can push to cocoapods

```
pod trunk register email@domain.com 'Your Name' --description='Senior ios developer'
pod trunk push YPlayer.podspec
```

if it that failed again because of source_files then you need to make new tag, and need to push podspec file and your code relatively, because  `pod trunk push` will check your your code using tag on git not locally like `pod lib lint YPlayer.podspec`